# How do I import an other family members photos to my iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, photos, iphone

My wife have a 16gb iPhone and her phone is now nearly full. I would like to import her photos to my iCloud account and free up some space on her phone. I have a 200GB subscription and she has a 50GB subscription the problem here is the phone's storage.

How can I import her photos to my iCloud account and move the photos off to her phone?

Comment: Have you considered activating iCloud Photo Library "optimize device storage" on her phone? That may solve the space issue. The other way around implies you adding her pictures to some of your devices.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. We both of us have (different) iCloud accounts and the optimize storage is enabled on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do what you want.

You don't state if you use iCloud Photo Library. If you don't, you can enable that and select the Optimize Device Storage option as @JaimeSantaCruz suggested. That will reduce the amount of space required on the device but will not eliminate it entirely.

There are a couple of workarounds but neither are ideal.

You could create a shared album, have her share everything she has on her device, then remove her from the shared album (and she can delete all the photos on her phone). The problem is that shared albums reduce the size of the pictures, so you won't be getting the originals.

If you have a Mac, the Photos app could be utilized, but it depends on your current set up. If she uses iCloud Photo Library already and the Mac is set to use the same iCloud account, everything should be in Photos already. If not, you'll need to hook up her iPhone to the Mac, and import everything. In either case, once everything is in Photos, you could copy all of the items into a new, non-iCL library (or an iCL library in a different user account that's hooked up to your Apple ID).

Comment: We both use iCloud Photo Library although different accounts

Comment: She has a different iCloud account than me. I have a Mac and is setup to use my iCloud account.